# React-router v4. Prevent scroll to top when using layout

Tags: react-router-v4

I am making a website using react-router v4 to navigate between views. So my layout have nav and footer, use Switch to switch different views. 
I already add scrollToTop function to make it scroll to top between different views.I used the function from here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration 
Let's say I have views Home and Solution. The problem is that inside the Solution view, I added another Switch ( child routes), so the path will be like this http://localhost:3000/solution/solution1.
So now when I clicked the child routes in Solution page, the page scroll to top which makes sense because the layout is wrapped by ScrollToTop function. But it is a switch tab, I don't want it to scroll to top, I want it to remain unchanged.
I tried to use ScrollToTopOnMount but no success.
Any ideas how to achieve this ? Thank in advance.